# Web3 js proper way to call a Reading contract function

Tags: web3js, javascript, web3-providers

So i recently took over a project that had been abandoned for a while, which involves an ECR20 smart contract and the use of the web3 library to communicate with the smart contract.
I've been trying for days to only call a read function or just a property, but I always get the following error:

```
Uncaught Error: The MetaMask Web3 object does not support synchronous methods like eth_call without a callback parameter
```

No matter which function i call, it's always the same. The contract instance is fine because there is another call to writing function in the same script and i'm using that same contract instance, but I'm not sure what is the proper syntax to call the funcion, so far i've tried these approaches (trying to call whiteListedAddresses function):

```
console.log(Coursetro.whiteListedAddresses(address).call()); //try 1

console.log(Coursetro.whiteListedAddresses(address)); //try 2

Coursetro.whiteListedAddresses(address).then(console.log); //try 3

Coursetro.whiteListedAddresses(address).call().then(function (result) {
  console.log(result + ' is the result');
}).then( function () {
  console.log("final call");
}); //try 4

Coursetro.whiteListedAddresses().call({'address':address}, result =>{
console.log(result);
}); //try 5
```

And other approaches, but nothing works, i can't get to read anything. Anyone knows what is the proper way to read from a contract?

**--EDIT--**

Contract initialization:

```
var CoursetroContract = web3.eth.contract(ABI);

 var Coursetro = CoursetroContract.at(contractAddress);
```

Like i said, this is working fine since other functions are being called and they are working, but they are all writting functions, and i'm trying to call reading functions.

web3js version is 0.20.7

these 4:

```
console.log(Coursetro.whiteListedAddresses(address).call()); //try 1

console.log(Coursetro.whiteListedAddresses(address)); //try 2

Coursetro.whiteListedAddresses(address).then(console.log); //try 3

Coursetro.whiteListedAddresses(address).call().then(function (result) {
  console.log(result + ' is the result');
}).then( function () {
  console.log("final call");
}); //try 4
```

output:

```
Uncaught Error: The MetaMask Web3 object does not support synchronous methods like eth_call without a callback parameter
```

and this one:

```
Coursetro.whiteListedAddresses().call({'address':address}, result =>{
console.log(result);
});
```

outputs:

```
Uncaught Error: Invalid number of arguments to Solidity function
```

which doesn't make any sense to me because the function only takes an address.

Comment: What is `Coursetro`?

Comment: @goodvibration Coursetro is the contract instance

Comment: Please share how you initialize it. Please also tell what version of web3.js you're using. Please also share the printout of each log specified in your question.

Comment: @goodvibration added the info you asked for.

Comment: @F_Bass You should consider using web3js v1.2.

Answer (score 1):

Finally got the correct syntax.

The callback function has to be passed as a parameter of the fuction you're trying to call, like this `contractInstance.myFunction(myParam, (err, res) => { //execute code with res });`

So at the end the code that worked for me looks like this:

```
Coursetro.whiteListedAddresses(myData, (err, res) => {
            if(!err){
                console.log('result is: '+ res);
            } else {
                console.error('result is: '+ err);
            }
            });
```